# Why can't UObject derived objects call BlueprintFunctionLibrary functions?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

My question is a very simple one.

Why can't UObject derived classes (direct inheritance) call functions from Blueprint Function Libraries?

__

**Edit:**

My question relates to Blueprints *only*.

An `Object` derived `Blueprint` seems to be incapable of calling *functions* from an *editor-created* `BlueprintFunctionLibrary`

Comment: Because they need a reference to the BPFL, but your BPFL is static, so you can include it and then call the functions.

Comment: @ColdSteel Thank you for the suggestion - I should have made it clear my question relates solely to blueprints

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t get it. I also saw this - I think its a bug in UE4 :-|

Comment: @ColdSteel Hm... Do you think I should post this on the Unreal Forums / Answer Hub? It feels like such a huge problem to be a bug

Comment: You can even open an issue on epics bug tracker, but dont expect it to be fixed, they only care about new features, they dont even fix release stopper bugs.

Comment: Very true... still major problems in even UMG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current bug in Unreal Engine.

---

The thread on the Answer Hub can be found here :

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/326679/cant-call-function-librarys-function-in-macro-libr.html#comment-326679-form

---

The Issue Tracker is here :

https://issues.unrealengine.com/issue/UE-22946